# Passing Touch Events From Overlaying Activity To Underlaying Activity in Android

Tags: java, android

I have created some activity which is transparent when some different app opens my activity starts and opens on top of that activity (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).

What i am trying to achieve is what action happens on my activity will reflect to other activity.I mean when i scroll down underlaying view will scroll.

I could NOT do that i have used some flags combinations but it did not work.

I could not pass touch events both activities at the same time. It just works at one view, i need to do what happens on top (transparent) activity , underlaying activity has get to same events.

```
 Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
        // window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SPLIT_TOUCH);
        // window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH);
        //window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE);


        setContentView(R.layout.trans);


        final View v = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);

        v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                Log.i("TAG", View !!!!!!!!");


                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. You can neither inject input events to other apps' Activities nor can you receive their input events (known as tapjacking).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with touch events, I am also not sure why would you want to do so.

That said, you can use [local broadcasts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) or [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) but it is a really bad idea, catch touch events in one Activity and pass to the other one after that.

Comment: Can i do that with EventBus lib?

Comment: Yes but you will have to try its performance (because of the frequency of touch events), you will sinply use eventBus.post in one activity and eventBus.register in the other one, again I would not really recommend it